Issue with session breaking after switching locales in Next.js v14 with i18next and Auth.js
I'm currently working on a web application using Next.js v14, i18next for localization, and Auth.js for authentication. The application functions as expected until I attempt to switch the locale from the default (AR) to another language (FR in my case). Upon switching locales, the session breaks and I encounter a nonsensical error.
1. Framework and Libraries:

Next.js v14 (latest)
(i18next i18next-resources-to-backend next-i18next react-i18next) for localization
next-auth v^5.0.0-beta.4 for authentication

2. Issue:
When switching the locale from the default language (AR) to another language (FR), the session breaks, and an error occurs.
3. Error Message:
The error message is
[auth][error] UnknownAction: Cannot parse action at /fr/api/auth/session .Read more at https://errors.authjs.dev#unknownaction
    at parseActionAndProviderId (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.27.0/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/utils/web.js:87:27)
    at toInternalRequest (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.27.0/node_modules/@auth/core/lib/utils/web.js:32:40)
    at Auth (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/@auth+core@0.27.0/node_modules/@auth/core/index.js:82:103)
    at httpHandler (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/.pnpm/next-auth@5.0.0-beta.13_next@14.0.4_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next-auth/index.js:139:80)
    at /home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:63257
    at /home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:133:36
    at NoopContextManager.with (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NoopTracer.startActiveSpan (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18093)
    at ProxyTracer.startActiveSpan (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:18854)
    at /home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:103
    at NoopContextManager.with (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:7062)
    at ContextAPI.with (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/@opentelemetry/api/index.js:1:518)
    at NextTracerImpl.trace (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/trace/tracer.js:122:28)
    at /home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:56774
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at Object.wrap (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:37057)
    at /home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:54547
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at Object.wrap (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:36306)
    at /home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:54509
    at AsyncLocalStorage.run (node:async_hooks:346:14)
    at eH.execute (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:53902)
    at eH.handle (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-route.runtime.dev.js:6:64515)
    at doRender (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1330:60)
    at cacheEntry.responseCache.get.routeKind (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1540:46)
    at ResponseCache.get (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/response-cache/index.js:49:26)
    at DevServer.renderToResponseWithComponentsImpl (/home/mohamed/Desktop/Projects/Training/final-razin/node_modules/.pnpm/next@14.0.4_react-dom@18.2.0_react@18.2.0/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1460:53)

. It seems to be quite large and nonsensical.
4. Steps to Reproduce:

Start the application in the default locale (AR).
Authenticate using Auth.js.
Navigate to a page where language switching is implemented.
Switch the language to FR (French).
Observe the error and broken session.

5. Expected Behavior:
Upon switching the locale, the application's session should remain intact, and the localization should be updated accordingly without any errors.
6. Additional Information:

I have verified that the issue persists even after updating to the latest version of Next.js and Auth.js.
I have thoroughly reviewed the configuration settings for i18next and Auth.js, but I cannot identify any obvious misconfigurations.
I suspect that the issue may be related to how session data is handled during the locale switch, but I'm not entirely sure.

7. Code Snippets:
// i18next configuration
import type{ Config } from "next-i18n-router/dist/types";

const i18nConfig: Config = {
  locales: ["ar", "fr"],
  defaultLocale: "ar",
};

export default i18nConfig;

// Auth.js configuration
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { db } from "@/server/db"
import { getUserById } from "@/data/user"
import { getTwoFactorConfirmationByUserId } from "@/data/two-factor-confirmation"
import type {  UserRole } from "@prisma/client"
import { getAccountByUserId } from "@/data/account"
import authConfig from "@/server/auth.config";
import type{ ExtendedUser } from "@/types";


export const config = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    error: "/auth/error",
  },
  events: {
    async linkAccount({ user }) {
      await db.user.update({
        where: { id: user.id },
        data: { emailVerified: new Date() },
      });
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account}){
      // Allow OAuth without email verification
      if (account?.provider !== "credentials") return true;

      const existingUser = await getUserById(user.id!);

      // Prevent sign in without email verification
      if (!existingUser?.emailVerified) return false;

      if (existingUser.isTwoFactorEnabled) {
        const twoFactorConfirmation = await getTwoFactorConfirmationByUserId(
          existingUser.id,
        );

        if (!twoFactorConfirmation) return false;

        // Delete two factor confirmation for next sign in
        await db.twoFactorConfirmation.delete({
          where: { id: twoFactorConfirmation.id },
        });
      }

      return true;
    },
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token.sub && session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }

      if (token.role && session.user) {
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).role = token.role as UserRole;
      }
      
      if (session.user) {
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).isTwoFactorEnabled = token.isTwoFactorEnabled as boolean;
      }
      
      if (session.user) {
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).firstName = token.firstName as string;
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).lastName = token.lastName as string;
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).country = token.country as string,
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).phone = token.phonev as string,
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).address = token.address as string, 
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).birthDay = token.birthDay as Date,
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).totalRevenue = token.totalRevenue as number,
        session.user.name = token.name,
        session.user.email = token.email!;
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).isOAuth = token.isOAuth as boolean;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token }) {
      if (!token.sub) return token;

      const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub);

      if (!existingUser) return token;

      const existingAccount = await getAccountByUserId(existingUser.id);

      token.isOAuth = !!existingAccount;
      token.firstName = existingUser.firstName;
      token.lastName = existingUser.lastName;
      token.country = existingUser.country,
      token.phone = existingUser.phone,
      token.address = existingUser.address, 
      token.birthDay = existingUser.birthDay, 
      token.email = existingUser.email;
      token.role = existingUser.role;
      token.totalRevenue = existingUser.totalRevenue;
      token.isTwoFactorEnabled = existingUser.isTwoFactorEnabled;

      return token;
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  ...authConfig,
} satisfies NextAuthConfig



export const { handlers:{GET, POST}, auth, unstable_update, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config)


// auth.config.ts file
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import type { NextAuthConfig } from "next-auth"
import { PrismaAdapter } from "@auth/prisma-adapter";
import { db } from "@/server/db"
import { getUserById } from "@/data/user"
import { getTwoFactorConfirmationByUserId } from "@/data/two-factor-confirmation"
import type {  UserRole } from "@prisma/client"
import { getAccountByUserId } from "@/data/account"
import authConfig from "@/server/auth.config";
import type{ ExtendedUser } from "@/types";


export const config = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/login",
    error: "/auth/error",
  },
  events: {
    async linkAccount({ user }) {
      await db.user.update({
        where: { id: user.id },
        data: { emailVerified: new Date() },
      });
    },
  },
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account}){
      // Allow OAuth without email verification
      if (account?.provider !== "credentials") return true;

      const existingUser = await getUserById(user.id!);

      // Prevent sign in without email verification
      if (!existingUser?.emailVerified) return false;

      if (existingUser.isTwoFactorEnabled) {
        const twoFactorConfirmation = await getTwoFactorConfirmationByUserId(
          existingUser.id,
        );

        if (!twoFactorConfirmation) return false;

        // Delete two factor confirmation for next sign in
        await db.twoFactorConfirmation.delete({
          where: { id: twoFactorConfirmation.id },
        });
      }

      return true;
    },
    async session({ token, session }) {
      if (token.sub && session.user) {
        session.user.id = token.sub;
      }

      if (token.role && session.user) {
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).role = token.role as UserRole;
      }
      
      if (session.user) {
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).isTwoFactorEnabled = token.isTwoFactorEnabled as boolean;
      }
      
      if (session.user) {
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).firstName = token.firstName as string;
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).lastName = token.lastName as string;
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).country = token.country as string,
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).phone = token.phonev as string,
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).address = token.address as string, 
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).birthDay = token.birthDay as Date,
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).totalRevenue = token.totalRevenue as number,
        session.user.name = token.name,
        session.user.email = token.email!;
        (session.user as ExtendedUser).isOAuth = token.isOAuth as boolean;
      }

      return session;
    },
    async jwt({ token }) {
      if (!token.sub) return token;

      const existingUser = await getUserById(token.sub);

      if (!existingUser) return token;

      const existingAccount = await getAccountByUserId(existingUser.id);

      token.isOAuth = !!existingAccount;
      token.firstName = existingUser.firstName;
      token.lastName = existingUser.lastName;
      token.country = existingUser.country,
      token.phone = existingUser.phone,
      token.address = existingUser.address, 
      token.birthDay = existingUser.birthDay, 
      token.email = existingUser.email;
      token.role = existingUser.role;
      token.totalRevenue = existingUser.totalRevenue;
      token.isTwoFactorEnabled = existingUser.isTwoFactorEnabled;

      return token;
    },
  },
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(db),
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  ...authConfig,
} satisfies NextAuthConfig



export const { handlers:{GET, POST}, auth, unstable_update, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth(config)

and this is the middleware.ts file contents:
import { i18nRouter } from "next-i18n-router";
import i18nConfig from "@/lib/i18n-config";
import type{ NextRequest } from "next/server";


export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  return i18nRouter(request, i18nConfig);
}

// Optionally, don't invoke Middleware on some paths
export const config = {
  // matcher: '/((?!api|static|.*\\..*|_next).*)',
  matcher: ["/((?!.+\\.[\\w]+$|_next).*)", "/", "/(api|trpc)(.*)"],
};

